# Why isn't in.good() the same as !in.fail()?

Tags: c++

I've read that the following is an anti-pattern:

```
while(in.good()) {
    // ...
}
```

But this is preferred:

```
while(operation) {
}
```

However, the stream has a conversion operator to bool that returns `!fail()`. Isn't `!fail()` the same as `good()`? If not, why aren't these two functions symmetrical? I'd expect it to be similar to `true == !false`.

Comment: its not about `good` vs `fail`, its about `while(in.good()) { ... }` vs. something like`while(getline(in, str)) { ... }`

Comment: See this handy table: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good

Comment: Because `fail` is not the only way a stream can stop being `good`.

Answer (score 3):

There's an excellent table at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good that explains state of an `std::istream` and the values various functions return.

The only time `while ( stream.good() )` and `while(stream)` will be different is when the contents of stream have been successfully read and EOF has been reached. At that time, `stream.good()` returns `true` while `(bool)stream` evaluates to `false.`

Answer (score 2):

`in.good()` is true if the previous read operation succeeded without EOF being encountered. (It is possible for EOF to be encountered even if a read operation succeeds.) So if `in.good()` is false, either the previous read operation failed -- in which case, the next one will also fail -- or EOF was encountered -- in which case the next read operation will also fail. So if `in.good()` is false, the next read operation will definitely fail. If we want to know whether it is worth trying to do a read operation, we should test `in.good()`.

But the fact that `in.good()` is true does not guarantee anything. Suppose that `in` ends with whitespace, which is normally the case since text files are required to end with a newline. Formatted read operations stop at the first whitespace character, and `unget` it back into the input stream, so if the previous read operation read the last data item, it still did not leave the stream at EOF, and `in` will still be `good`. [See note 1]. So if your loop looks like this:

```
while (in.good()) {
  in >> x;
  /* Do something with x assuming that it is valid */
}
```

then you won't notice when the last `in >> x` failed, and you'll end up using an undefined value of `x` in the last loop. (Probably the last value will be processed twice.)

The same thing would happen if your loop was `while (!in.bad())`, or `while (!in.eof())`.

What you really want is to check whether `in >> x` succeeded. Nothing else. And the classic way to do that is:

```
while (in >> x) {
  /* If we get here, x has a legitimate value */
  ...
}
```

`in >> x` just returns `in`, so that's exactly equivalent to

```
while (in >> x, in) {
  /* ... */
}
```

In other words, `bool(in)` is `false` precisely when the previous operation failed, and `true` precisely when it succeeded. That's not the same as `in.good()` because we don't (yet) want to test whether EOF was encountered.

#### Notes:

1. As stated in the first paragraph, it is *possible* for a read to succeed and also set EOF. One way that can happen is that the file does not end with a newline character. That's pretty rare, but you shouldn't rule it out. And the fact that it can happen is precisely why `in.bad()` doesn't examine the eof flag: `in.bad()` being false definitely means that the previous read operation failed.

Answer (score 0):

in.good() is equal to:  [[ios documentation]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/)

```
! ( in.eof() || in.fail() || in.bad() )
```